# How do you append info to an environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables

The method `export vname=value` will override the original value. I want a way to append to the old value by colon.

Any idea how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
export vname=${vname}:appendedtext
```

Demo:

```
$ export foo=bar
$ echo $foo
bar
$ export foo=${foo}:baz
$ echo $foo
bar:baz
```